# How to detect attachement inside MS Office files

Tags: java, ms-office

I've got a web server with java on which can be uploaded doc/docx and xls/xlsx files. There's a possibility that they can contain viruses as an attachement, maybe some *.exe or *.com file. How can I check that they don't?

Comment: how should a `.doc` file be infected with a virus? do you mean the macros?

Comment: you can make some `.bat` file, insert it inside document and send it to user. User will open it, start `.bat` (a lot of users don't know what it is) and infect his computer

Comment: you mean that there is a bat file hidden in the archive of the doc file? (rename doc to zip, insert bat file in zip and rename back)

Comment: no, you can just drag any file with mouse in your .doc file and it will be inside as attachement. It won't start until user will open .doc file and double-click to attachement, but some users can do this

Comment: Your title is not related to your problem, right? Your question is how to detect viruses in attachments.

Comment: IMHO file server should not analyze files so deep, I would only check some basic rules like *.exe files, and leave other corner cases to user responsibility.

Comment: Not really. I can just forbid all attachements with *.exe, *.jar and other "dangerous" extensions.. In that case I just check for attachements, check attachement extension and
will permit or forbid to save file.

Comment: Unfortunately users already launched such files and infected our local network with "worms". That's why I'm searching for some solution

Comment: `filename.zip\word\embeddings` there you find so called `oleObject`s. these are saved as `.bin` file. if you rename the object to a `.txt`, you can open it and find the filename in it. this also includes the file extension

Comment: thanks, I guess this will work for me